# How to avoid returning `null` values with Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

Suppose I have the following query on my React frontend:

```
query {
     getResponse {
          someFieldA
          someFieldB
     }
}
```

And my express-graphql server defines the response to this query as:

```
const GetResponseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
     name: 'GetResponseType',
     fields: () => ({
          someFieldA: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
          someFieldB: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
     })
})
```

Now suppose my GraphQL services defines `getResponse` as the following:

```
. . .
     getResponse: {
          type: GetResponseType,
          resolve: () => {
               return {
                    someFieldA: true
               }
          }
     }
. . .
```

The response to this request would return the following:

```
{
     data: {
          getResponse: {
               someFieldA: true,
               someFieldB: null,
          }
     }
}
```

How can I avoid `someFieldB` being null here, if it is not returned from `getResponse`?

If it matters, I'm trying to implement a feature switch, which returns a key-value pair object, where the key is a specific feature and the value is *always* `true`. If a specific feature is `undefined`, then it is turned off. For separate reasons, I cannot return `false` for features that are turned off.

What can I do here? The expected response to this query is the following:

```
{
     data: {
          getResponse: {
               someFieldA: true,
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: all queried/requested fields MUST be returned ... not returned [by resolvers] and nullable are returned as `null`, for not nullable error MUST be thrown - graphQL specs requirements ... for some "separate reasons" [if no false returned] you MUST accept `null`s in the response => handle them as `false` on FE